# Is subscribing inside RxJS tap, bad practice for an asynchronous logic?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am having two http requests where the second one (Log request) should be subscribed after the first one (Order request) emits a value and I do some logic that **should not be blocked by the Log request** and the result of log request is ignored.

As I understand that tap is

> Used to perform side-effects

https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap

and since I assume Log request and its response here is a side-effect to the Order request, is it bad practice to subscribe inside tap? Is there a more slick and RxJS way of handling this?

```
const order = of('2- created order').pipe(
  delay(100),
  tap(console.log)
);

const log = of('4- logged info to log server').pipe(
  delay(500),
  tap(console.log)
);

console.log('1- started creating order');
order
  .pipe(tap(() => log.subscribe()))
  .subscribe(() => console.log("3- didn't wait for log server"));
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-up9gs8?file=index.ts)

Comment: In general yes because there's not way to unsubscribe. However, in your case it looks like you don't even want to unsubscribe and you don't care about the result and you probably don't even want it to block `complete` notification (like `ignoreElements()` operator would) so I guess this is an exception where it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it definitely is bad practice.

You're right that `tap` is there for side effects but those should not involve other streams, they should be simple side effects like assigning variables or console logging and stuff.

The issue is that you generally do not want to subscribe inside a `subscribe` on inside the `pipe` because doing so makes for very unpredictable and difficult to maintain code.

For example your `subscribe` inside the `tab` looks innocuous enough, but imagine if you were listening to a continuous stream of data, how many subscriptions would you have? would you care to track them all to unsubscribe, wouldn't that end up quite difficult to understand/debug, etc...

The problem with your code is that you are somewhat thinking in an imperative way (something like "do this and then that, and then...") instead of thinking in terms of streams.

So basically in my opinion, instead of thinking something like "how do I do this before that?" you should be thinking about how you handle the stream and the order of operations you can perform on it.

In your case, is there any reason why you'd want to print the third message inside the subscribe and not in the `pipe`?

Why not just doing the following?

```js
order
  .pipe(
    tap(() => console.log("3- didn't wait for log server")),
    switchMap(() => log)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

(like here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-aace8i?file=index.ts)

---

If I may, I would like to analyse your question...

Starting with

> I am having two http requests where the second one (Log request)
> should be subscribed after the first one (Order request) emits a value

that just seems a simple case of having an initial observable (Order) and needing to use a mapping operator to move to a different one (Log), I assumed that you want to discard the first and move to the second so I chose `switchMap` (alternatively you could use `concatMap` or `mergeMap`)

Then we get to:

> and I do some logic that should not be blocked by the Log request and
> the result of log request is ignored.

since we already thought of how to handle the 2 observables, if we read your sentence it really spells out that we just want a side effect to occur between the first and second observable, and it ignores the streams' values anyways, so it clearly calls for a simple `tap`

---

I am sorry for the rather long message I hope it does not sound too pedantic :P

What I basically wanted to say is that you should always look at your streams and sort of think how to fit all together in accordance to rxjs programming style and what you need, and not whether some ways of doing something is acceptable or not, as that makes me realy thing that you already had suspicions on whether it not being the best solution.

Comment: "is there any reason why you'd want to print the third message inside the subscribe and not in the pipe?" 
Yes, because It is subscribed by another service somewhere else in the app and they need to access the result of order request. The third message is just a placeholder here for that.

Comment: mh... so basically you want to create an observable in a service that you can subscribe to in another service and have the subscription also trigger the log as a side effect? I am not 100% sure I am getting the full picture, but if I understood it correctly I would suggest to, instead of subscribing inside the pipe, use a subject and call next onto that, creating in that way a the side effect you wanted and you'd have a single subscription to that subject in the log service.

Comment: is that any helpful? but yeah anyways, I think that there are ways around it and that you do not want to subscribe in the pipe! :P

Comment: ah yeah I just noticed that @BizzBob has given an answer similar to what I am thinking

Answer (score 2):

As @martin mentions in the comment, it's generally bad to subscribe inside a pipe (*not specifically tap, but any operator*) because there's no way handle cleaning up subscriptions.

Generally, it's preferred to use one of the "[Higher-Order Mapping Operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)" because they handle subscribing, emitting, and unsubscribing from your observable.

> Is there a more slick and RxJS way of handling this

Not sure if this would be considered "slick" or not :-), but I think it gives a nice separation of concerns if a [`Subject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects) is used as a dedicated stream of log messages; then create a single subscription to have your server logging logic executed:

```js
const logMessage$ = new Subject<string>();
logMessage$
  .pipe(mergeMap(logToServer))
  .subscribe();
```

Then in your other code, instead of subscribing, you can call `logMessage$.next()` to trigger the server logging logic without impeding the flow of your `order` stream:

```js
order.pipe(tap(o => logMessage$.next(o)));
```

Here's an updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67958700?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=75).

Comment: Sorry I am not getting why you want to use the `mergeMap` there, wouldn't a simple non-piped subscription be enough for the `logMessage$` subject?

Comment: If `logToServer` only did some synchronous logic, then mergeMap would not be needed.  But, in this case `logToServer` returns an observable which needs subscribed to in order to execute, so mergeMap is needed to handle the subscription.