# Chain observables and invoke void method

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have 3 services: Current user service, OtherUsername service, MessageService. And MessageService has method that need's User and OtherUsername:

```
createHubConnection(user: IUser, otherUsername: string): void {
        this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(this.hubUrl + "message?user=" + otherUsername, {
                accessTokenFactory: () => user.token
            })
            .withAutomaticReconnect()
            .build();
        this.hubConnection.start().catch(error => console.log(error));

        this.hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessageThread", messages => {
            console.log("fsafsafsa")
            this.messageThreadSource.next(messages);
        });

        this.hubConnection.on("NewMessage", message => {
            this.messageThread$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(messages => {
                this.messageThreadSource.next([...messages, message])
            })
        })
    }
```

After all that i want to call method `groupMessages()` and i tried to do this but it's not going into tap:

```
    currentUser: IUser;
    this.currentUser.currentUser$.pipe(
        switchMap((user: IUser) => {
          this.currentUser = user;
          return this.threadUsername.getUsername();
        }),
        tap((other: string) => {
          this.messageService.createHubConnection(this.currentUser, other) // It's not getting there
        }))
        .subscribe(res => this.groupMessages());
```

groupMessage() is working with `message$` observable that get's initialized in `createHubConnection()` method

Comment: Is `IUser` an interface or a service? Imho, you should provide its definition too.

Comment: @VasileiosKagklis it's interface. There is a currentUserService that has `currentUsers$` of type Observable<IUser>

Answer (score 0):

Your `tap` callback is getting called actually. You should be able to `console.log` within the callback function. The problem as to why

```ts
this.messageService.createHubConnection(this.currentUser, other)
```

is not invoked, is because the observable returned from it, is not being subscribed to.

#### Solutions

Either solution listed below works. Assess each and pick one.

1. You `.subscribe` within the `tap` callback. [Not that I recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67958700/7931817), but it's a valid solution.

   ```ts
   // your tap logic should look something like below
   tap((other: string) => {

     this.messageService.createHubConnection(this.currentUser, other).subscribe();
     // you might want to add unsubscription logic

   }))
   ```
2. Flatten [higher-order](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators#higher-order-observables) observables in some way. For your use-case, I would do something like the following, using the [`mapTo`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/mapTo) operator:

   ```ts
   this.currentUser
     .currentUser$
     .pipe(
       switchMap((user: IUser) => {
         this.currentUser = user;
         return this.threadUsername.getUsername();
       }),
       switchMap((other: string) => {
         return this.messageService                      //  return observable to be subscribed down the chain...
           .createHubConnection(this.currentUser, other) //  that creates hub connection from source observable value...
           .pipe(
             mapTo(other)                                //  after which, return the very same source observable value just like what tap does
           );
       })
     )
     .subscribe(res => this.groupMessages());
   ```

   The only downside to this is that the execution of `this.groupMessages()` will have to wait until `this.messageService.createHubConnection()` completes. Nevertheless, it does the job without introducing problems with the first approach.

Comment: Im getting error because `createHubConnection` method is returning void

Comment: Depending on the content of `createHubConnection`, I might be able to help with your specific problem. Ideally you will want to return an observable of the asynchronous process you're trying to do inside that method.

Comment: i added content of `createHubConnection`

Comment: Reading your `createHubConnection`, I'm afraid I can't afford to help you as it only leads to more specific questions. I suggest you follow the first solution instead, if you want your code to "just work."